# setup aws cognito 2fa after google login via cognito

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

AWS cognito allows 2fa after username, password login but not after social signin.
Is there any way to enforce user for two factor authentication after google or any other identity provider login?

Answer (score 3):

If you allow your users to use 3rd party Auth options like Google, Facebook, etc. Then it's up to those providers to mandate MFA/2FA. If you want to enforce MFA for whatever reason, then don't allow federated authentication. Documentation on how to add MFA with cognito: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/user-pool-settings-mfa.html

Comment: I already have 2fa for normal username and password login but I want to to add 2fa after social signin is finished similar to the case after username and password are verified in normal login. In azure active directory this feature is available. I just want to see if similar thing can be implemented via cognito or amplify

Comment: Can't seem to find it anywhere in the documentation as as per the understanding it's just not possible.